# Querydsl - Sum with type Duration

Tags: querydsl, duration

I have a Entity that have a Duration type field and I would like to sum this field with QueryDsl.
Is it possible? I was search on querydsl.com and dont find a solution.

The sum accepts only number, but my field is Duration type.

```
public static <E extends Number> AbstractGroupExpression<E,E> sum(Expression<E> expression)
```

Any sugestions, please?

Comment: Hi Diego! Please try to add a little more information into the question. What have you tried so far? Is there any elastic article you can refer to that might have a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I was facing the same issue. I resolved it by using `Expressions.numberPath()` as below.

```
final NumberPath<Long> durationPathAsLongPath = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, durationPath.getMetadata());
```

Then you can use `sum()` on the resulting `NumberPath`.